# How to setup a Pub/Sub in nanomsg between a C and Python sides?

Tags: python, c, publish-subscribe, nanomsg

I'm trying to learn the [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg) library.

I'm using the code examples of both versions C and Python. I'm trying to subscribe to the C service with a Python script, but nothing is happening.

Here's both of my code :

Python subscriber

```
from __future__ import print_function
from nanomsg import Socket, PAIR, PUB
s2 = Socket(PAIR)
while(True):
    s2.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
    s2.send(b'hello nanomsg #1')
    s2.send(b'hello nanomsg #2')
    s2.close()
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>  /* For htonl and ntohl */
#include <unistd.h>

#include <nanomsg/nn.h>
#include <nanomsg/pubsub.h>

/*  The server runs forever. */
int server(const char *url)
{
    int fd; 

    /*  Create the socket. */
    fd = nn_socket (AF_SP, NN_PUB);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "nn_socket: %s\n", nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
        return (-1);
    }

    /*  Bind to the URL.  This will bind to the address and listen
        synchronously; new clients will be accepted asynchronously
        without further action from the calling program. */

    if (nn_bind (fd, url) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "nn_bind: %s\n", nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
        nn_close (fd);
        return (-1);
    }

    /*  Now we can just publish results.  Note that there is no explicit
        accept required.  We just start writing the information. */

    for (;;) {
        uint8_t msg[2 * sizeof (uint32_t)];
        uint32_t secs, subs;
        int rc;

        secs = (uint32_t) time (NULL);
        subs = (uint32_t) nn_get_statistic (fd, NN_STAT_CURRENT_CONNECTIONS);

        secs = htonl (secs);
        subs = htonl (subs);

        memcpy (msg, &secs, sizeof (secs));
        memcpy (msg + sizeof (secs), &subs, sizeof (subs));

        rc = nn_send (fd, msg, sizeof (msg), 0);
        if (rc < 0) {
            /*  There are several legitimate reasons this can fail.
                We note them for debugging purposes, but then ignore
                otherwise. */
            fprintf (stderr, "nn_send: %s (ignoring)\n",
                nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
        }
        sleep(10);
    }

    /* NOTREACHED */
    nn_close (fd);
    return (-1);
}

/*  The client runs in a loop, displaying the content. */
int client (const char *url)
{
    int fd;
    int rc;

    fd = nn_socket (AF_SP, NN_SUB);
    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "nn_socket: %s\n", nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
        return (-1);
    }

    if (nn_connect (fd, url) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "nn_socket: %s\n", nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
        nn_close (fd);
        return (-1);        
    }

    /*  We want all messages, so just subscribe to the empty value. */
    if (nn_setsockopt (fd, NN_SUB, NN_SUB_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "nn_setsockopt: %s\n", nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
        nn_close (fd);
        return (-1);        
    }

    for (;;) {
        uint8_t msg[2 * sizeof (uint32_t)];
        char hhmmss[9];  /* HH:MM:SS\0 */
        uint32_t subs, secs;
        time_t t;

        rc = nn_recv (fd, msg, sizeof (msg), 0);
        if (rc < 0) {
            fprintf (stderr, "nn_recv: %s\n", nn_strerror (nn_errno ()));
            break;
        }
        if (rc != sizeof (msg)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "nn_recv: got %d bytes, wanted %d\n",
                rc, (int)sizeof (msg));
             break;
        }
        memcpy (&secs, msg, sizeof (secs));
        memcpy (&subs, msg + sizeof (secs), sizeof (subs));

        t = (time_t) ntohl(secs);
        strftime (hhmmss, sizeof (hhmmss), "%T", localtime (&t));

        printf ("%s <pid %u> There are %u clients connected.\n", hhmmss,
            (unsigned) getpid(), (unsigned) ntohl(subs));
    }

    nn_close (fd);
    return (-1);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc;
    if ((argc == 3) && (strcmp (argv[2], "-s") == 0)) {
        rc = server (argv[1]);
    } else if (argc == 2) {
        rc = client (argv[1]);
    } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s <url> [-s]\n", argv[0]);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit (rc == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I run the C code by doing

`./pubsub_demo tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 -s`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Time to learn to use a C debugger.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala With all due respect -- **Negative, Sir** -- There is no such C debugger, that will show and help the principally & conceptually missed target on connecting a non-compatible Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern above the ISO-OSI-Layer 7. As attempted above, a **`PAIR`** archetype will never become able to "speak" together with a **`PUB`** -lisher. And no C debugger will ever help with this. A better problem-domain knowledge will. ( a cool skill listed -- "MS DOS games" -- indeed :o)  )

Comment: @user3666197 with all due respect, "nothing happens" is not a problem description. That's why I suggested that a C debugger be used to confirm that *something* is happening somewhere.

Comment: Yes, your principal methodology is clear & sound. What I tried to advise was yet to notice, that it will take aaaaaaaaaages before a **C-side debugger** will help user to realise, the **Python** side is doing a conceptual nonsense above ISO-OSI-L7, while C-side is working bit-by-bit exactly as per the RFC-specification says. Peace to Oulu :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C code looks good. It comes from [**here**](https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/blob/master/demo/pubsub_demo.c).

A simpler version of C `NN_PUB` server and `NN_SUB` client also [**exists**](https://github.com/dysinger/nanomsg-examples).

There are a few problems with presented the Python code.

1) In [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg) we have to **match behavioural-"protocols"**. In order to receive a `NN_PUB` broadcast from the C server, we have to have a matching **`SUB`**, not a `PAIR`, socket on the Python side.

2) Connect to the same endpoint-**`transport-class://address:port`** as `NN_PUB` socket `nn_bind()`-s to. There is no need to do it in the loop.

3) The socket has to have **`SUB_SUBSCRIBE`** option set.

4) **`SUB`** socket is for listening, it is not designed to `.send()` anything.

An untested Python program may look in-principle as follows:

```
# import appropriate modules for the nanomsg socket
from nanomsg import Socket, PUB, SUB, SUB_SUBSCRIBE

# open Python's SUB socket matching the NN_PUB socket on the C side 
s2 = Socket(SUB)
# s2 should be >= 0

# connect the socket to the same endpoint as NN_PUB server
ret1 = s2.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
# ret1 should be 0

# subscribe to everything:
ret2 = s2.set_string_option(SUB, SUB_SUBSCRIBE, '')
# ret1 should be 0

# receive messages:
while(True):
    message = s2.recv()
```

You can also look at Python test [**PUB/SUB example**](https://github.com/tonysimpson/nanomsg-python/blob/master/tests/test_pubsub.py)

I hope it helps.